# NASM jmp wonkiness

Tags: macos, nasm, i386

I'm writing a Forth inner interpreter and getting stuck at what should be the simplest bit.  Using NASM on Mac (macho)

```
msg  db "k thx bye",0xA     ; string with carriage return
len  equ $ - msg            ; string length in bytes

xt_test:
    dw xt_bye     ; <- SI Starts Here

    dw 0
    db 3,'bye'
xt_bye dw $+2       ; <- Should point to...
    push dword len  ; <-- code here
    push dword msg  ; <--- but it never gets here
    push dword 1
    mov  eax, 0x4   ; print the msg
    int 80h
    add  esp, 12
    push dword 0
    mov eax, 0x1    ; exit(0)
    int 80h

_main:
    mov si,xt_test ; si points to the first xt
    lodsw          ; ax now points to the CFA of the first word, si to the next word
    mov di,ax
    jmp [di]       ; jmp to address in CFA (Here's the segfault)
```

I get Segmentation Fault: 11 when it runs.  As a test, I can change _main to

```
_main:
    mov di,xt_bye+2
    jmp di
```

and it works

EDIT - Here's the simplest possible form of what I'm trying to do, since I think there are a few red herrings up there :)

```
a dw b
b dw c
c jmp _my_actual_code

_main:
    mov si,a
    lodsw
    mov di,ax
    jmp [di]
```

EDIT - After hexdumping the binary, I can see that the value in b above is actually 0x1000 higher than the address where label c is compiled. c is at 0x00000f43, but b contains 0x1f40

Comment: Maybe you should post the complete source ? The msg, the _syscall (is it just the "int 0x80" ?)

Comment: right - _syscall is just int 80h, the only thing missing is msg & len, which I'll go fix :)

Comment: Looks like this has something with the segment registers. 0x1000 offset may come from DS=0x100 or something. Sorry, I only have an old PowerPC G5 mac, so I just can't test your x86 asm exactly :)

Comment: I really appreciate your help with this, Viktor - it makes sense that it might assume DS instead of CS - I'll give that a go and let you know.

Comment: Sure, all these nice assembly puzzles remind me a lot from the past :) It's a pleasure for me to help :)

Answer (score 0):

First, it looks extremely dangerous to use the 'si' and 'di' 16-bit registers on a modern x86 machine which is at least 32-bit.

Try using 'esi' and 'edi'. You might be lucky to avoid some of the crashes when 'xt_bye' is not larger than 2^16.

The other thing: there is no 'RET' at the end of xt_bye.

One more: see this linked question [Help with Assembly. Segmentation fault when compiling samples on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914316/help-with-assembly-segmentation-fault-when-compiling-samples-on-mac-os-x)

Looks like you're changing the ESP register to much and it becomes unaligned by 16 bytes. Thus the crash.

One more: the

```
jmp [di]
```

may not load the correct address because the DS/ES regs are not used thus the 0x1000 offset.

Comment: Right - I'm afraid I over simplified in order to post here - it's exiting at the end of the routine at xt_bye so it's not necessary to return (also, it's not being called) - Also, I get the same result with the esi & edi registers, but the eventual goal is to get it to run in real mode as a boot sector

Comment: I guessed that it is a return-less procedure, so I didn't put it as a main source. The esi/edi might not be an issue also.